# WebStorm format error for vue jsx

Tags: vue.js, webstorm, jsx

I use `Reformat code` action in WebStorm but find it's not compatible with ESLint. The error is:

> expect indentation 24 but found 25

Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: You can just remove a space so that the indentation is correct and the linting will be ok.

Comment: but I always reformat..

Comment: Please check your Code Style formatting rules for HTML -- must be one with wrapping attributes -- as you can see it tries to put them on the same column so it looks nice. Otherwise -- adjust your ESLint rules...

Comment: @LazyOne thank you, I adjust align attributes on webstorm